# Let $f(x) $ satisfy $ \int_{a}^{b} f^{2}(x) \,dx \leqslant f(a) + f(b)$ ,Prove that:$f(x) \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f(x) \in C(-\infty, + \infty)$ satisfy $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f^{2}(x) 
dx \leqslant f(a) + f(b)$ for $\forall a,b \in R$

Prove that:$f(x) \equiv 0$

I have known that $f(x) \geqslant 0$,but I can't continue.

Comment: what if $f\equiv 1$ ? then this integral is just $b-a$ and this might be $\le 1+1$

Comment: @infinity: Not for all real $a,b$.

Comment: @NateEldredge ok, now that the claim is fixed the statement seems reasonable.